# htaccess RewriteRule issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to .htaccess and I have found a few articles and I've tried to make it work, but keep failing.

I have the following in my .htaccess file:-

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    RewriteBase /mydomain.com/
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_ssl.c>
    RewriteBase /
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ index.cgi/$1 [L]
```

However, I want to be able to go to **mydomain.com/more-info**, but this rule is making it **mydomain.com/index.cgi/more-info**

How can I make is so that "more-info" is exempt from this rule?

Thank you in advance.

---

So, Ulrich suggested the following...

```
#if not /more-info
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/more-info$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ index.cgi/$1 [L]
```

...but I still get '404 Not Found'. The more-info directory contains index.htm, and if I turn this RewriteEngine off, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^((?!more-info)[^.]*)$ index.cgi/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a RewriteCond Directive before

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ index.cgi/$1 [L]
```

that exempts /more-info. Something like -

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} != /more-info
```

You may find some examples here -> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Answer (score 0):

As below

```
#if not /more-info
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/more-info$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ index.cgi/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but for some reason this doesn't seem to be working for me. I still get 404 Not Found.